# On my grapher, $(\cos t, \sin (t+1))$ generates a geometric figure. What is that figure?

Tags: geometry, parametric

On Wolfram Alpha I am getting a graph like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sin+t%2Ccos%28t%2B1%29%29

Is this an ellipse? I really don't know how to find it.

Comment: It's an ellipse, but you may be interested to know that it's a special case of a so-called ["Lissajous curve"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve). See the "$a=b$" discussion in the Wikipedia entry for information about the elliptical case.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is : you can write $\sin(1+t)=\sin(1)\cos(t)+\sin(t)\cos(1).$ Then your graph is the set $$\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\\sin(1)&\cos(1)\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t)\\\sin(t)\end{pmatrix} \mid t\in\mathbb{R}\} $$ which is a regular linear transformation of the unit circle.

Answer (score 2):

Well in your WA submission you've got the functions switched around, but that's equivalent to a phase change so it doesn't really make much of a difference.

We're graphing the pair of functions $x = \cos{t}$ and $y = \sin{(t+1)}$, but let's expand and rearrange the second one using the trigonometric identity $\sin{(\alpha + \beta)} = \sin{\alpha}\cos{\beta} + \cos{\alpha}\sin{\beta}$. So:

\begin{eqnarray}
y & = & \sin{(t+1)} \\
  & = & \sin{t}\cos{1} + \cos{t}\sin{1} \\
y - \cos{t}\sin{1} & = & \sin{t}\cos{1} \\
y - x \sin{1} & = & \sin{t}\cos{1} \\
(y - x \sin{1})^2 & = & (\sin{t}\cos{1})^2 \\
 & = & \sin^2{t}\cos^2{1} \\
 & = & (1 - \cos^2{x})\cos^2{1} \\
 & = & (1 - x^2)\cos^2{1} \\
y^2 - 2xy\sin{1} + x^2 \sin^2{1} & = & (1 - x^2)\cos^2{1} \\
x^2 + y^2 - 2xy\sin{1} & = & \cos^2{1}
\end{eqnarray}

Which is, indeed, an ellipse, and [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2-2xy%20sin%281%29%20%3D%20cos%5E2%281%29) even identifies it as such.

Comment: Great answer! This is nearly the exact same answer I was going to post.